# How can show UILocalNotification when receive remote notification?

Tags: ios, xcode, uilocalnotification

How can show `UILocalNotification` when receive remote notification and when I am using the app? not `UIAlertView`?

I am using this code, but it's not showing anything

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
{
    for (id key in userInfo) {
        NSLog(@"key: %@, value: %@", key, [userInfo objectForKey:key]);
    }


    localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
    NSString *message = [[userInfo valueForKey:@"aps"] valueForKey:@"alert"];
    localNotification.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;
    localNotification.alertBody = message;
    localNotification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
    localNotification.fireDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:0];
    localNotification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
    localNotification.alertAction = @"ok!!!";
    [application scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification];
}
```

Also I tried:

```
[application presentLocalNotificationNow:localNotification];
```

But it's not working too.

Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apple doesn't support showing local notifications from a foreground state.

[Local Notification Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/WhatAreRemoteNotif.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH102-SW1)

However you could try using this:

https://github.com/avielg/AGPushNote

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 1):

If the app is running while the notification is delivered, there is no alert displayed on screen. The application automatically calls its delegate’s application:didReceiveLocalNotification: method

Answer (score -3):

In order to see UI while your app is in the foreground, you'll need to handle showing it yourself.

You can make your own view and animate it in from the top of the screen, then animate it back out after some delay.

As other answers mention, there are open-source projects available which may make this simpler to implement: In addition to `AGPushNote` I have published a pod [linked in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36664043/395295) which has similar functonality.

Comment: Please also avoid posting multiple answers all just linking to your own product as it may be perceived as spam. Instead tailor each answer to the question, and remember to provide a code example showing how to use this tool

Comment: Yep, you've foiled my plan to get rich off the MIT License. ;)