# AGPushNote alternative for Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

Just as the title says, do you know any alternative of AGPushNote for Swift ?

In order to better understand what I was searching for when I found out on SO about this, I would like to .. "detect" when push notifications are incoming and app is active so I can prevent the notifications from showing up and do some of my own stuff instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just [published a pod](https://github.com/charliewilliams/CWNotificationBanner) that does exactly that.

Example usage:

```
import CWNotificationBanner

override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    let message = Message(text: "You have an alert")
    NotificationBanner.showMessage(message)

    let message = Message("You have an alert", displayDuration: 2)
    NotificationBanner.showMessage(message)

}

override func viewWillDisappear() {
    super.viewWillDisappear()

    NotificationBanner.cancelMessage(message, animated: false)
    NotificationBanner.cancelAllMessages()
}
```

Feel free to check out & contribute if you like!

Comment: Just linking to your own library or tutorial is not a good answer. Linking to it, explaining why it solves the problem, providing code on how to do so and disclaiming that you wrote it makes for a better answer. See: [**What signifies “Good” self promotion?**](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/182212/200235). Also avoid answering off-topic questions, this question is off-topic as a tool recommendation as per the [help/on-topic].

Comment: @Kyll I'd agree if the question were "How do I accomplish some abstract task?". In this case, the question is "Is there a pre-existing library that has similar functionality to AGPushNote?" I can add explanation, but I don't see how this isn't answer exactly the queston the OP posted.

Comment: Exactly, because this question is off-topic and **should not be answered** for the very reason you provided.

Comment: @Kyll if you feel the question is off-topic why are you only downvoting the answer I provided?

Comment: It's one of those moments one feels bad of being part of the community. Thank you for making me feel like that. And @buildsucceeded , I upvote and mark as correct your answer, will surely do changes and fork the project , thank you again !